# Trouble concatenating netcdf files with ncrcat

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a list of netcdf files that I am trying to concatenate along the time dimension.

I am attempting to use the steps outlined [here](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Concatenate-the-Time-Dimension-of-netCDF-Files-with-NCO), which seem simple enough. However, I am running into some errors (likely some small/stupid oversight on my part...)

When I try to first make time a record dimension, I am using the following command:

```
ncks -O --mk_rec_dmn time TiMREX_20080526_000001.nc test_out.nc
```

This, however, give me the following error:

```
ncks: invalid option -- '-'
```

It seems like this is just some simple syntax/typo error on my part, but try as I might I can' find anything wrong.

Just to be sure, when I run a ncdump -h on the file, it confirms that there is indeed a time dimension

```
ncdump -h TiMREX_20080526_000001.nc
netcdf TiMREX_20080526_000001 {
dimensions:
    time = 1 ;
    bounds = 2 ;
    x0 = 300 ;
    y0 = 300 ;
    z0 = 40 ;
```

Additionally, if I try to skip this step and just go right to the ncrcat part...

```
ncrcat -O TiMREX_20080526_000001.nc TiMREX_20080526_000733.nc test_out.nc
```

I get the following error:

```
ncopen: filename "TiMREX_20080526_000001.nc": Not a netCDF file
```

Which is especially odd...I'm pretty confident it is indeed at netCDF file (I just ran ncdump on it after all, and have no problem viewing it with ncview...)

Any thoughts? What simple step am I embarrassingly missing?

Comment: Sometimes double-dash "--" command line options and their arguments have to go last.  Have you tried `ncks -O TiMREX_20080526_000001.nc test_out.nc --mk_rec_dmn time`?  (Haven't actually tried this on `ncks`; may or may not matter here)

Answer (score 3):

This is a weird error as your command looks syntactically correct. To be sure, I copied it to my machine where it ran as expected, with no 'invalid option' error. Thus I am unable to reproduce the problem. Based on the error message you report, it seems as though you might (somehow) be using a character that the system does not understand as a dash. In other words, the error you report is what I would expect if ncks received a funky character that looks like a dash but is not really a dash. Maybe when you copy it to stackoverflow it gets converted to a dash, so it works for me (try copying your own command above back into your console). Make sure the dash character you type is the same as the minus sign on a normal keyboard, and something else. Some keyboard/character sets make characters that look similar to dashes but are not ASCII dashes. Good luck.